# Viewing all of the info in Chrome's console

Tags: google-chrome

When I click a button on the stie, in firebug->console->all, I can see the info, something like:

```
GET http://enfura.mysite.org/index.php?eID=tx_ajax&action=popup&uid=4805
```

But in chrome->console->all, I can not see it, why? is that a way that i can also get this kind of info in chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, XHRs are not displayed in Chrome's console like they are in Firebug's.

You need to right click the console and enable that via the *Log XMLHttpRequests* option.

[image: Enable XHRs in console]